# Claws mail configuration to use two panes layout

Tags: email, claws-mail

Is it possible to remove the preview pane in claws mail? I mean to have only two panes: Left with the folder tree and right with the e-mail list.

Then when I double click on the message or press Enter key, separate window with the message has to be opened.

It seems the whole functionality is already in Claws - it can open the messages in separate window. But I can't figure out how to remove the preview pane.

I know it was possible in Sylpheed though.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck /View/Show or Hide/Message View.
Alternately you can click the little downwards-arrow between Message List and Message View

Comment: It folds the preview pane, but only until I press **ENTER** on a message. I want when I press **ENTER**, the message to be open in separate window.